# Time displayed wrongly on Heroku but correctly on localhost using moment

Tags: javascript, heroku, momentjs

I have been stuck with this problem for nearly 5 hours! Tried many solutions online and exhausted them all but to no avail. Would appreciate any form of help!

I have a string on my localhost:

```
datestring = 'Fri, 04 Aug 2017 14:15:17 GMT'
```

Passing it through moment would give me:

```
datestring = moment.utc(datestring).format('LLLL')
>> Friday, August 4, 2017 2:15 PM
```

This is shown on my localhost and it is correct. However, when I deploy it to Heroku, the date and timing becomes wrong:

```
>> Thursday, August 3, 2017 6:24 PM
```

My timezone is UTC +8. I thought that by using the moment.utc function, it would have already standardised the datetime and therefore the time shown on Heroku should be also UTC +8.

Upon checking some solutions online, I have also set the TZ config variable in heroku to be Asia/Singapore to ensure that Heroku is at UTC +8 timezone.

I am suspecting whether this is due to Heroku server being located in US therefore resulting in this discrepancy.

Can someone point me to the right solution?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Heroku uses UTC by default. To change this, set your preferred timezone using the TZ Database Timezone format (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

For example, for Pacific Time:

`$ heroku config:add TZ="America/Los_Angeles"`

Comment: Yup I've done this! but it's still showing the wrong datetime on heroku! :(